# How to save xxd or hexdump output to a simple file?

Tags: linux, hexdump, xxd

Is there a way to save the output to a file directly from the terminal?
I give xxd command to a file on my terminal:

```
xxd image.jpg
```

and it gives me its contents in hex:

```
0003c450: 0124 9248 0492 4920 1249 2480 4924 9201  .$.H..I .I$.I$..
0003c460: 2492 4804 9249 2012 4924 8049 2492 0124  $.H..I .I$.I$..$
0003c470: 9248 0492 4920 1249 2480 4924 9201 2492  .H..I .I$.I$..$.
0003c480: 4804 9249 2012 4924 8049 2492 0124 9248  H..I .I$.I$..$.H
0003c490: 0492 4920 1249 2480 4924 9201 2492 4804  ..I .I$.I$..$.H.
0003c4a0: 9249 2012 4924 8049 2492 0124 9248 0492  .I .I$.I$..$.H..
0003c4b0: 4920 1249 2480 49db ba49 203f ffd9       I .I$.I..I ?..
```

What I want is to save these values in a file so that I can use them in another program. Is it possible from the terminal? If not how do I incorporate xxd or hexdump into a program?

Comment: Do you mean like `xxd image.jpg xxd.dump` or `xxd image.jpg > xxd.dump`? If so, you may have a look into `man xxd` "_If no outfile is given (or a '-' character is in its place), results are sent to standard output._" and [What are the shells control and redirection operators](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159513/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
xxd image.jpg > image.txt
```

I now have a text file of the hex representation of the image.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that when you say you want to use the output "in another program", you mean you're going to compile it into something. This is what the `-i` option is for: generate an include file:

```
xxd -i image.jpg > image.h
```

Then `#include` image.h in your project and use the associated variables.